# What does Symbol Observable do in a class?

Tags: javascript, symbols

I am using a library whose  class import from [SymbolObservable](https://github.com/benlesh/symbol-observable)

```
import SymbolObservable from 'symbol-observable';
class Spring {
      [SymbolObservable] = () => {
        return {
          subscribe: observer => {
            function notify(spring) {
              observer.next(spring.getCurrentValue());
            }

            const listener = {
              onSpringActivate: notify,
              onSpringUpdate: notify,
              onSpringAtRest: notify,
            };
            this.addListener(listener);

            return () => this.removeListener(listener);
          },
          [SymbolObservable]() {
            return this;
          },
        };
      };
}
```

What exactly is going on here? The documentation is not saying much. I do not see any `subsrcribe` anywhere in the library. What does the `[SymbolObservable] = () => {}` on a class does? What does this do

```
  [SymbolObservable]() {
        return this;
   },
```

Link to [library](https://github.com/facebook/rebound-js/blob/master/src/Spring.js)

Comment: For what it's worth, it's a ponyfill for [`Symbol.observable`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-observable). Scrolling down on the page gives some insight as to what exactly an `Observable` is and why they're useful.

Comment: Do you understand the syntax and are only confused about the semantics of `SymbolObservable`?

Comment: I just read about the syntax but I do not understand what happens when `   [SymbolObservable] = () => {` is defined in a class. And no subscribe anywhere in the library also confuse me. I just added link to library.

Comment: @raj What do you mean by "what happens"? That's a class field creating an arrow function on that property in the constructor. Nothing else. Similarly, `[SymbolObservable]() {
        return this;
   }` obviously defines a symbol-keyed method that returns the instance itself when called. Are you asking *why* they are doing this?

Comment: @Bergi Ya why are they doing it? What is the purpose of `SymbolObservable` rather than a usual class method.

Comment: Because that special key makes the object implement the observable protocol. Just like [the iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) works.

Comment: @Bergi If an iterable is implemented , it makes things like for loop possible in that object. Like that does this implementation makes `subscibe` obervable method possible on the class? And what is the `          [SymbolObservable]() {
            return this;
          },` for?

Comment: Yes, it means it makes it possible to observe the object. (Not sure whether there's new syntax for that, check the proposal). If the method just `return this;`, then the observer object is the same as the observable object - just like every iterator is iterable by returning itself.